# Screen orientation when opening links inside Facebook native app mobile browser

Tags: facebook, mobile

Is there anyway to avoid Facebook opening a link in its own web browser or to show it on landscape mode? I've noticed it has portrait orientation locked and my app needs to be run over landscape, but it seems to not allow you to rotate the device.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

2021 here, and Facebook iOS browser still doesn't rotate with the device.